# Selecting by row in pandas using df.loc

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

Using jupyter notebooks I have an excel file imported as a pandas dataframe, named 'clean.' When trying to select data by the row name clean.loc('Method Blank') throws an error saying 'Method Blank' is not in the index. I believe it might have something to do with the index of the database having a null value where there is subsequent data. Any suggestions?

```
clean.shape

(8, 2)

type(clean)

pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

clean

        Phenol Batch QC Check   Unnamed: 1
NaN     NaN     PNL Results     Acceptance
QC Parameter    (ug/L)  Criteria
Method Blank    1.1284  <2 ug/l
Reporting Limit (RL) Verification Standard (2.0 ug/L)   2.5318  ±40%
Reporting Limit (RL) Verification Standard (4.0 ug/L)   4.0967  ±40%
Laboratory Control Sample (LCS)     20.2061     ±20%
Quality Control Sample (QCS)    19.9668     ±20%
Calibration Verification (20.0 ug/L)    20.1203     ±20%

clean.loc['Method Blank']

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _has_valid_type(self, key, axis)
   1505                 if not ax.contains(key):
-> 1506                     error()
   1507             except TypeError as e:
```

Comment: What happens if you use `clean.loc['Method Blank ']?` What happens if you `print clean.index`?  Also, can you post your dataframe sample in a way that can be easily pasted into someone else's code, so they can try and replicate the error?

Comment: I suspect a space is the problem. Try clean.index = clean.index.str.strip(). Then do clean.loc

Comment: print (clean.index) returns:

MultiIndex(levels=[[], ['                    2)  Red strike through indicates failure.', '                    3)  Save worksheet using LIMS worksheet ID # for the file name', 'Calibration Verification (20.0 ug/L)', 'Date:', 'Instructions:  1)  Fill in blue cells with appropriate data.', 'LIMS Worksheet ID#', 'Laboratory Control Sample (LCS)', 'Matrix Sample ', 'Matrix Spike', 'Matrix Spike Duplicate', 'Method Blank', 'QC Parameter'...

I'm not sure how to paste the dataframe sample.

Comment: clean.index = clean.index.str.strip() returns:

Can only use .str accessor with Index, not MultiIndex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not aware it was a multi-indexed dataframe.

Using clean.ustack(level=0).loc['Method Blank'] I was able to get it to return the corresponding data.